# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqQB5KKJCh0) to install opencv ubuntu 14.04. I created a C ++ project in QT, after the execution of this. an error message is displayed:

```
    g++ -m64 -o test main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o  
     -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib 
    -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann 
    -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 


//error is here
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [test] Error 1
    06:00:12: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop)
    When executing step 'Make'
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Well, install the required libraries.

Comment: which I have used for installation?

thank you

Comment: You're missing the extra modules in this case - see here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: @y300, thank you for your post, I solved two other packages but this package "/ usr / bin / ld: can not find -lopencv_xfeatures2d" is not yet installed or added.

thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Can someone help me to ensure the installation of this xfeatures2d-dev library and thank you